# Full Calender V.5 Width not Autoadjusting when sidebar is toggle is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When the the sidebars toggle is used `.main` div's width get expanded, but a gap is occurred on right side of calendar.

**View Example in fullscreen**

```js
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
    });

    calendar.render();
    $('.icon').click(function(){
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass('in');
    });
  });
```

```css
.sidebar{
  background:#eeeeee;
  height:100vh;
  width:200px;  
}
.h-100{
  height:100vh!important;
}
.main{
  flex:1;
  padding:20px
}
.icon{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.in{
  width:25px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex h-100">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="icon text-right px-2">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-text-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="main">
     <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Is there any full calendar function which can be called when toggle button is pressed to readjust the width. Or any other work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call

```
calendar.render();
```

again each time the sidebar button is clicked.

Demo:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      timeZone: 'UTC',
      initialView: 'timeGridWeek',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
      },
      events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json'
    });

    calendar.render();
    $('.icon').click(function(){
      $('.sidebar').toggleClass('in');
      calendar.render();
    });
  });
```

```css
.sidebar{
  background:#eeeeee;
  height:100vh;
  width:200px;  
}
.h-100{
  height:100vh!important;
}
.main{
  flex:1;
  padding:20px
}
.icon{
  cursor: pointer;
}
.in{
  width:25px!important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar-scheduler@5.7.0/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex h-100">
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="icon text-right px-2">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-text-left" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M2 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0-3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h11a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-11a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5z"/>
</svg>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  <div class="main">
     <div id='calendar'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```